# banking application basichttpsbinding security

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, security

IS WCF (basicHttpsBinding) with security mode ="TransportWithMessageCredential" considered secure enough for banking data or would I have to come up with my own  custom binding to ensure security and cross platform support? What alternative web service frameworks exist that would suffice for banking security and cross platform support? Thanks.

Comment: You need to ask Microsoft if you want to know what they think...

Comment: let me rephrase the question to ask the sof community

Comment: What does "secure enough for banking data" mean? Are you, perhaps, working in a industry with regulations that would spell out the requirements for you?

Comment: @c45207: thanks for your comment. Sort of, what i'm trying to get at mean is would the binding be able to secure the data efficiently enough and be considered secure by regulations in developed countries in lets say north america and Europe.

Comment: @c45207: if not what do banking apps use to exchange sensitive data with the server? I'm relatively new to the way banks handle customers mobile banking data and would just like a little more insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example from this space is the [PCI Security Standards Council](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/), a group that develops and maintains the security standards typically used in the payment card industry (e.g., credit and debit cards).

That being said, you might want to spend some browsing [the Information Security StackExchange](http://security.stackexchange.com). There are lots of existing questions that you can read, like the following:

- [How to convince coworkers to not store credit card numbers ourselves](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18677/how-to-convince-coworkers-to-not-store-credit-card-numbers-ourselves)
- [How does SSL work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-work)
- [How do certification authorities store their private root keys?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24896/how-do-certification-authorities-store-their-private-root-keys/24906)

Maybe just start with [the questions with the largest number of votes](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the information security stackexchange.